# How to make a snow fall on web page text?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this JavaScript code for snow falling effect. It's working really nice,
but I decided to create a snow falling on web page text. I have tried, but not getting how to do it.

How to make snow fall on that "I love you" text? http://jsfiddle.net/DgrxX/22/

I have already seen in VB6 code where snow fall on text. If it is possible in Visual Basic 6 seven years ago, why not today in JavaScript or CSS3 or jQuery?

```
function vp(woh)
{
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
         viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
         viewportheight = window.innerHeight
     }

     else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
         && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
         'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
     {
         viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
         viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
     }

     else
     {
           viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
           viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
     }
        if (woh == 'w')
        {
            return viewportwidth;
        }
        else if (woh == 'h')
        {
            return viewportheight;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
function snowflake()
{
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    this.radius = Math.random()*2;
    this.color = "white";
    var tobefallingSpeed = Math.random() * 100;
    this.fallingSpeed = tobefallingSpeed + 30;
}
function render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (b=0;b<snowflakes;b++)
    {  
        sf[b].y+=0.4;
        if(sf[b].y> canvas.height){
         sf[b].y = 0;   
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(sf[b].x,sf[b].y,sf[b].radius,sf[b].radius);
    }
}
function main()
{
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - then;
    render();
    then = now;
}
then = Date.now();
var int = self.setInterval(main,1);
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = vp('w');
canvas.height = vp('h');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var numberofSnowflakes = 100;
var sf = [];

for (i=0;i<numberofSnowflakes;i++)
{
    sf[i] = new snowflake();
    snowflakes = i;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it "pile up" on the text?

Comment: thx for reply,yes but not getting it.

Comment: Ankit - that would involve calculating the exact position of the individual letters pixels and some serious physics motor. Someone might have an answer, but that's not something you "just do". Check this out: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/snowstorm/ - it seems to have some "stick" functionality. I highly doubt that it works on the individual letters though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have seen a few answers but the asker wants the snow to be **exclusively piling up on the text**. Exact piling (according to the snow in background) would be really very difficult but I would like to suggest a (maybe complex) working method.

Make images.

A lots of them. With the text 'I love You' and contents of snow different in each. This maybe similar to creating picture frames from a video.

Define a `div`. Change your picture every x seconds, where x depends on number of images you have made.

You can use the following code for changing image:

```
function change_background( new_image_source ) {

  var myimage = $( '#myimage' );

  myimage.attr( 'src', new_image_source );

  setTimeout( function () {

    change_background( 'new image source here' );

  }, 100);

}
```

This code will change the image after `0.1`. This can hopefully give you the required effect but you will need to make a lot of pictures that differ slightly. I would make lots of pictures for my gf (if I had one).

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark this as the chosen answer.